# Python - Can't parse a tuple to DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, list, tuples

I am receiving multiple values in a list that came in the following forma:
[(id_customer, name_customer, category, start_date, value), (id_customer, name_customer, category, start_date, value),(id_customer, name_customer, category, start_date, value)...]

What I want is to parse this list into a single dataframe. For that I am trying to convert the list into tuple and then create my dataframe. But I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (3, 1), indices imply (3, 5)
```

My initial list have the following data:

```
[('1', 'OIL COMPANY,LDA', 'ENERGY', '2010-11-10', 13.), ('100', 'SPORTS ,LDA', 'SPORT', '2020-11-01', 12.), ('7', 'INFORMATIC,LDA', 'IT', '2019-01-03', 23.)]
```

My code:

```
tuple_del = tuple(myList)
df = pd.DataFrame(tuple_del, columns=['id', 'name', 'category', 'date', 'value'])
```

And I am trying to get:

```
id, name, category, date, value
1,'OIL COMPANY,LDA', 'ENERGY', '13.'
100,'SPORTS ,LDA', 'SPORT', 2020-11-01, '12.'
7, 'INFORMATIC,LDA', 'IT', '2019-01-03', '23.'
```

Comment: `list` and `tuple` is working with your example data.

Comment: your data is working...

Comment: yes :( strange, because I f I pass the list in a list variable it works fine. But I am using the interface from "PySimpleGUI" and I am receiving the list from a Listbox, using the values from the list to convert to dataframe it gives me that error...

Answer (score 0):

Inorder to get your target, you just add to your code:

```
df=df.set_index('id')
```

The complete code:

```
import pandas as pd

myList=[('1', 'OIL COMPANY,LDA', 'ENERGY', '2010-11-10', 13.), ('100', 'SPORTS ,LDA', 'SPORT', '2020-11-01', 12.), ('7', 'INFORMATIC,LDA', 'IT', '2019-01-03', 23.)]
df = pd.DataFrame(myList, columns=['id', 'name', 'category', 'date', 'value'])

df=df.set_index('id')

print(df)
```

The output is

```
                name category        date  value
id                                              
1    OIL COMPANY,LDA   ENERGY  2010-11-10   13.0
100      SPORTS ,LDA    SPORT  2020-11-01   12.0
7     INFORMATIC,LDA       IT  2019-01-03   23.0
```